# jQuery UI Button Style for ASP.NET Button

Tags: asp.net, css, jquery-ui

How can I use [jQuery UI buttons style](https://jqueryui.com/button/) for my ASP.NET buttons? How can I do it in my Skin or some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not try to use the `CssClass` property of the button and set it the relevant Jquery CSS class for that button?

This possibly might work - you can verify what the correct Jquery classes are and update

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEnter" runat="server" Text="Jquery Asp Button" CssClass="ui-button ui-widget" />
```

Edit:

Just thought of this now, but since the Asp button results in and if you are targeting all submit buttons on a page

```
<input type="submit" name="btnEnter" value="Click me!" id="btnEnter">
```

you could use some Jquery which selects all the inputs where the type equals submit and apply the Jquery CSS classes in one swoop.

I think it will be like this (syntax not verified)

```
$(":submit").addClass('ui-button ui-widget');
```

Answer (score 1):

asp.net button are different from normal button. To style it the best way is this:

```
<asp:button runat="server" ID="btnAspNet">Click me</asp:button>
```

get the correct ID from the asp.net button in jQuery

```
var btn = $('[id$=btnAspNet]');
```

add style from jQuery UI

```
btn.addClass('Ui class name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember all asp.net buttons are rendered as submits so add the following script:

```
// All buttons     
$(":submit").addClass('ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only');
```

or

```
// A specific button
$('#<%= button1.ClientID %>').addClass('ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only');
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, to **add** button class:

```
<script> 
    $(document).on('ready', function () {
        document.getElementById('<%=btnCreate.ClientID%>').className = 'btn disabled';
    });
</script>
```

In JavaScript, to **remove** button class

```
<script> 
    $(document).on('ready', function () {
        document.getElementById('<%=btnCreate.ClientID%>').className = '';
    });
</script>
```

In ASP.NET CodeBehind:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCreate" runat="server" Text="Create Account"
    Class="btn disabled" OnClick="btnCreate_Click" />
```